# Linux Kernel DTSI File Cannot Compile from Yocto for BeagleBone

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel, yocto

I am using the Texas Instruments official Yocto SDK to build a complete BSP for the Beaglebone X-15 ( TI AM5728 Processor ).

The entire SDK builds great for the MACHINE=am57xx-evm type from the SDK. Later SDKs include the MACHINE=beagle-x15, but I need this older version with Linux kernel 4.4.

The Linux kernel 4.4 in this SDK does have beagle-x15 device tree fragments included, but the machine configuration for the beagle x15 was not present, so I included the 1 conf file for the new machine from a later SDK.

The problem is that the Device Tree fails to compile - there is a syntax issue as shown in this traceback:

```
| Error: /home/user/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work-shared/beagle-x15/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/beagle-x15-cmem.dtsi:1.1-2 syntax error
| FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
| scripts/Makefile.lib:293: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/am57xx-beagle-x15-revc.dtb' failed
| make[3]: *** [arch/arm/boot/dts/am57xx-beagle-x15-revc.dtb] Error 1
| arch/arm/Makefile:333: recipe for target 'am57xx-beagle-x15-revc.dtb' failed
| make[2]: *** [am57xx-beagle-x15-revc.dtb] Error 2
| Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
| make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
| Makefile:24: recipe for target '__sub-make' failed
| make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
| WARNING: /home/user/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/beagle_x15-linux-gnueabi/linux-ti-staging/4.4.41+gitAUTOINC+f9f6f0db2d-r7a.arago5.tisdk60/temp/run.do_compile.121513:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/beagle_x15-linux-gnueabi/linux-ti-staging/4.4.41+gitAUTOINC+f9f6f0db2d-r7a.arago5.tisdk60/temp/log.do_compile.121513)
```

Here is the entire DTSI file that fails to compile:

```
    / {
        reserved-memory {
                #address-cells = <2>;
                #size-cells = <2>;
                ranges;

                cmem_block_mem_0: cmem_block_mem@a0000000 {
                        reg = <0x0 0xa0000000 0x0 0x0c000000>;
                        no-map;
                        status = "okay";
                };

        cmem_block_mem_1_ocmc3: cmem_block_mem@40500000 {
            reg = <0x0 0x40500000 0x0 0x100000>;
            no-map;
            status = "okay";
        };
        };

        cmem {
                compatible = "ti,cmem";
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

        #pool-size-cells = <2>;

                status = "okay";

                cmem_block_0: cmem_block@0 {
                        reg = <0>;
                        memory-region = <&cmem_block_mem_0>;
                        cmem-buf-pools = <1 0x0 0x0c000000>;
                };

        cmem_block_1: cmem_block@1 {
            reg = <1>;
            memory-region = <&cmem_block_mem_1_ocmc3>;
        };
        };
};
```

Here is the beagle-x15.conf file:

```
#@TYPE: Machine
#@NAME: BeagleBoard X15
#@DESCRIPTION: Machine configuration for the BeagleBoard X15

require conf/machine/include/dra7xx.inc

KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "am57xx-beagle-x15.dtb am57xx-beagle-x15-revb1.dtb am57xx-beagle-x15-revc.dtb"

MACHINE_GUI_CLASS = "bigscreen"

SERIAL_CONSOLE = "115200 ttyS2"

UBOOT_MACHINE = "am57xx_evm_config"

WKS_FILE = "sdimage-bootpart.wks"
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES = "MLO u-boot.img"
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "tar.xz wic.xz"

do_image_wic[depends] += "mtools-native:do_populate_sysroot dosfstools-native:do_populate_sysroot"

# UBI information.  Note that this is board and kernel specific.  Changes
# in your kernel port may require changes in these variables.  For more
# details about this board please see
# http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/UBIFS_Support

# do ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -m 7 -O 2048
# From dmesg:
# UBI: smallest flash I/O unit:    2048
# UBI: logical eraseblock size:    126976 bytes
# from ubiattach stdout:
# UBI device number 0, total 1988 LEBs
MKUBIFS_ARGS = "-F -m 2048 -e 126976 -c 8192"

# do ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -m 7 -O 2048
# from dmesg:
# UBI: smallest flash I/O unit:    2048
# UBI: physical eraseblock size:   131072 bytes (128 KiB)
# UBI: sub-page size:              512
# UBI: VID header offset:          2048 (aligned 2048)
UBINIZE_ARGS = "-m 2048 -p 128KiB -s 512 -O 2048"
```

How can I get this DTSI file to compile? Thanks.

UPDATE: It turns out the Ubuntu DTC compiler also fails ( Version 1.4 ):

```
dtc -O dtb -o /home/user/Desktop/test.dtb /home/user/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work-shared/beagle-x15/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/beagle-x15-cmem.dtsi
Error: /home/user/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work-shared/beagle-x15/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/beagle-x15-cmem.dtsi:1.1-2 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dtc compiler by default treats the Device Tree version as 0 if no version is specified. Syntax for version 0 is different from version 1. So you need to add,

```
/dts-v1/;
```

as your fist line of device tree file.

Apart from this, usually you need to compile `.dts` file, not the `.dtsi` (which is include) directly. So you need to define according device tree file with `.dts` extension including `.dtsi` files.